# SQL query to extract strings from comma delimited string

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I want to extract data from MS Access database to MS Excel using VBA.

I know the code to extract but facing issues manipulating the column.

I want to extract string before first comma, and then string after second and before third comma, and then string after third comma.

As an example. Let's say I have one column called fruits and it has data as

```
Banana,Apple,Orange,Grapes
```

I want to create four columns which will have Banana on first, Apple on second, Orange on third and Grapes on fourth column.

Below is what I tried for first column.

```
SQL = "SELECT SUBSTRING(Fruits,0,CHARINDEX(',',Fruits) as column1 from tablename"
```

Comment: The _best_ advice here is to stop storing CSV strings in your tables, especially when you consider each CSV value to be a single point of data.  Instead, get each fruit string onto a separate record.  Fruits love having some breathing room!

Comment: Due to some limitation, we can't create more columns on the tables. So, looking for these manipulation to get data on my excel.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Data NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Banana,Apple,Orange,Grapes'

DECLARE @DataXML XML = '<a>' + REPLACE('Banana,Apple,Orange,Grapes', ',', '</a><a>') + '</a>'

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT T.c.value('.','varchar(255)')
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.c)
    FROM @DataXML.nodes('/a') T(c)
) DS ([value], [col])
PIVOT
(
    MAX([value]) FOR [col] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) PVT
```

---

```
SELECT 'Banana,Apple,Orange,Grapes'
 AS [my_column]
INTO [my_table]


WITH DataSource (DataXML) AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<a>' + REPLACE([my_column], ',', '</a><a>') + '</a>' AS XML)
    FROM [my_table] 
)

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT T.c.value('.','varchar(255)')
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.c)
    FROM DataSource
    CROSS APPLY [DataXML].nodes('/a') T(c)
) DS ([value], [col])
PIVOT
(
    MAX([value]) FOR [col] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) PVT
```

Comment: We can't declare variables as there is one field in my database which have thousands of rows. I want to write a query on the basis of field name and then extract.

Comment: @PraveenKUMAR You can use CTE if you don't want to declare variables. Do you want to show you how?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tiny helper function and use *Split*:

```vb
Public Function GetField( _
    ByVal AllFields As String, _
    ByVal Index As Integer) _
    As String
    
    GetField = Split(AllFields, ",")(Index)
    
End Function
```

and then:

```vb
SQL = "Select GetField([Fruit], 0) As Fruit From YourTable"
```

Comment: When I run this SQL query using vba in a procedure.. it says function doesn't exist. I have also created the tiny helper function outside.

Comment: If located in a code module, compiled and saved, it should be reachable.

Comment: it says undefined function.. I have saved in the same module

Comment: The same module as ..? But, try to create a new module and move the function to this.